# Count an island and its start and end

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Table]

What I would like is to count the islands of data based of the Day_Ranking column, so the output would look like something similar to this:

```
Person           Start Date           End Date           Count
 45286            2021-08-26           2021-09-07         8
 13914            2021-09-22           2021-10-01         7
 32914            2021-01-10           2021-01-10         1
 32914            2021-01-12           2021-01-13         2
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?
I am doing this is with Oracle SQL

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement and `INSERT` statements for your sample data as **TEXT** that can be copy/pasted and executed (and not as images hidden behind a link that we cannot copy/paste).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform a row-by-row comparison:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY person
  ORDER BY day_ranking
  MEASURES
    FIRST(date_value) AS start_date,
    LAST(date_value) AS end_date,
    COUNT(*) AS count
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN (successive_ranks* last_rank)
  DEFINE successive_ranks AS day_ranking + 1 = NEXT(day_ranking)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (person, date_value, day_ranking) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01',  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-02',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-04',  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-05',  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-07', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-09', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-01', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-02', 16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-03', 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-04', 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-05', 19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2022-01-01', 25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2022-01-03', 27 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PERSON | START_DATE | END_DATE | COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-22 | 09-JAN-22 | 6 |
> | 2 | 01-JAN-22 | 05-JAN-22 | 5 |
> | 3 | 01-JAN-22 | 01-JAN-22 | 1 |
> | 3 | 03-JAN-22 | 03-JAN-22 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ffb96e94e990a44fa0b634ad24977055)*

Comment: That worked great, thank you! I apologize for not adding the creation/insert statements and will add those next time!